# How to get records from azure eventhub to databricks

Tags: azure, events, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using community addition of databricks.
I an trying the following code I am not getting any records:

```
var streamingSelectDF = 
  streamingInputDF
   .select(get_json_object(($"body").cast("string"), "$.id").alias("id"),get_json_object(($"body").cast("string"), "$.CarName").alias("CarName"))

streamingSelectDF.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").option("truncate", false).start().awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Kindly help me for the same

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if the event hub is receiving any messages or not ?

If not, can you send some sample events to eventhub and see whether the events are being received by it.

Sample code to read from event hub and print data to the console.

```
// Build connection string with the above information
val namespaceName = "<EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE>"
val eventHubName = "<EVENT HUB NAME>"
val sasKeyName = "<POLICY NAME>"
val sasKey = "<POLICY KEY>"
val connStr = new com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.ConnectionStringBuilder()
            .setNamespaceName(namespaceName)
            .setEventHubName(eventHubName)
            .setSasKeyName(sasKeyName)
            .setSasKey(sasKey)

val customEventhubParameters =
  EventHubsConf(connStr.toString())
  .setMaxEventsPerTrigger(5)

val incomingStream = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(customEventhubParameters.toMap).load()

incomingStream.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").option("truncate", false).start().awaitTermination()
```

You can refer to this link for more details :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/databricks/scenarios/databricks-stream-from-eventhubs

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you start streaming without existing checkpoint, the start position from which consumption happens is the end of the stream, so until you send new messages to the topic, you won't get any existing data.  You can change that by specifying corresponding option of the EventHubs conf:

```scala
val cs = "YOUR.CONNECTION.STRING"
val ehConf = EventHubsConf(cs)
  .setStartingPosition(EventPosition.fromStartOfStream)
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("eventhubs")
  .options(ehConf.toMap)
  .load()
df.select(get_json_object(($"body").cast("string"), ....)
```

See [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/structured-streaming-eventhubs-integration.md#eventposition) for description of the all possible options.